# function row.add() not work in my function:

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

function row.add no work correctly, to create the datatable:

```
var target=$(table.dt-table); //i test and only exist one.
target.DataTable(options);
```

try to add a row in same function:

```
if(addrow!=null){target.row.add(addrow).draw();} //addrow i a var with array.
```

i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

i need add a row to existing datatable. in any way with row.add() or adding html raw code.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()#Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [api documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) on [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add())

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable(); // <-- use the returned object from .DataTable() and not the jQuery object

table.row.add( {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "5421"
    } ).draw();
```